# Олимпиадная задача "Маленькие знаменатели"

Tags: олимпиада

Ограничение по времени: 2 секунды.
Ограничение по памяти: 512 Мб.

### Условие:

Даны две дроби `a`/`b` < `c`/`d`
с целыми неотрицательными числителями и целыми положительными
знаменателями, а также выбрано некоторое целое положительное `N`. Рассмотрим все несократимые дроби `e`/`f` с целыми положительными числителями и знаменателями, не превосходящими N, лежащие
между этими двумя дробями: `a`/`b` <
`e`/`f` <
`c`/`d` . Выпишем их в конечную последовательность в порядке
возрастания сначала знаменателей, а потом числителей: дробь `e1`/`f1`
будет в этом списке раньше `e2`/`f2`
,
либо если `f1` < `f2`, либо если `f1` = `f2` и `e1` < `e2`. Ваша цель — вывести n первых дробей в этой
последовательности (или всю последовательность, если в ней менее `n` дробей).

### Формат входных данных:

В первой строке находятся шесть целых чисел `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `N`, `n` — две данные дроби, ограничение
на числители и знаменатели и количество дробей, которые необходимо вывести (0 6 a 6 1018
,
1 <= `b`, `c`, `d`, `N` <= 1018
, 1 <= `n` <= 200 000). Гарантируется, что `a`
`b` <
`c`
`d`.

### Формат выходных данных:

В первой строке выведите целое число `n'` — количество дробей, которые вы выведете. В следующих `n'`
строках выведите сами дроби в нужном порядке: в `i`-й строке должны быть целые `ei` и
`fi`
, разделённые пробелом — взаимно простые числитель и знаменатель `i`-й дроби (1 <= `ei`
, `fi` <= N).
Число `n'` должно либо равняться `n`, либо лежать в пределах от 0 до n − 1 и равняться количеству
несократимых дробей между `a`
`b`
и
`c`
`d`
, у которых числители и знаменатели целые положительные и не
превосходят `N`.

### Примеры:

Ввод:
`0 1 1 1 5 10`

Вывод:

```
9
1 2
1 3
2 3
1 4
3 4
1 5
2 5
3 5
4 5
```

Ввод:
`55 34 68 42 90 1`

Вывод:

```
1
89 55
```

Ввод:
`49 33 45 30 50 239`

Вывод:

```
0
```

### Моё решение

Я использовал `Дерево Штерна-Броко` для генерации дробей.

Почему-то на большинстве тестов даёт `Wrong Answer`, на некоторых `Time Limit`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class fraction {
public:
    long long numerator, denominator;

    fraction() : numerator(0), denominator(0) {}

    fraction(long long numerator, long long denominator) : numerator(numerator), denominator(denominator) {}

    bool operator==(const fraction & fr) {
        return numerator == fr.numerator && denominator == fr.denominator;
    }

    bool operator!=(const fraction & fr) {
        return numerator != fr.numerator || denominator != fr.denominator;
    }
};

bool compare(const fraction& fr1, const fraction& fr2) { // для set
    if (fr1.denominator != fr2.denominator)
        return fr1.denominator < fr2.denominator;
    return fr1.numerator < fr2.numerator;
}

bool operator>(const fraction& fr1, const fraction& fr2) {
    if (fr1.denominator != fr2.denominator)
        return (double)fr1.numerator * fr2.denominator > (double)fr2.numerator * fr1.denominator;
    return fr1.numerator > fr2.numerator;
}

bool operator<(const fraction& fr1, const fraction& fr2) {
    if (fr1.denominator != fr2.denominator)
        return (double)fr1.numerator * fr2.denominator < (double)fr2.numerator* fr1.denominator;
    return fr1.numerator < fr2.numerator;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const fraction& fr) {
    str << fr.numerator << ' ' << fr.denominator;
    return str;
}

long long gcd(long long a, long long b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        long long tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp % b;
    }
    return a;
}

int main() {

    long long a, b, c, d, N; int n;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> N >> n;

    {
        long long gcd1 = gcd(a, b), gcd2 = gcd(c, d);
        a /= gcd1, b /= gcd1;
        c /= gcd2, d /= gcd2;
    }

    set<fraction, decltype(&compare)> fractionSet(&compare);

    // два массива для генерации дерева
    fraction* arr1 = new fraction[262144];
    fraction* arr2 = new fraction[262144];

    int len1 = 3, i2 = 0; // индексы 1 и 2 показывают отношение к arr1 и arr2

    arr1[0] = fraction(0, 1), arr1[1] = fraction(1, 1), arr1[2] = fraction(1, 0);

    {
        // по окончании этого блока в arr1 остаётся две или больше дробей, причём первая дробь минимальна и больше a/b, вторая максимальна и меньше c/d, и все дроби между ними правильно сгенерированы
        fraction sample1 = fraction(a, b), sample2 = fraction(c, d);
    label:
        if (sample1 > arr1[1]) {
            arr1[0] = arr1[1];
            arr1[1] = fraction(arr1[0].numerator + arr1[2].numerator, arr1[0].denominator + arr1[2].denominator);
            goto label;
        }
        if (sample2 < arr1[len1-2]) {
            arr1[len1-1] = arr1[len1-2];
            arr1[len1-2] = fraction(arr1[len1-3].numerator + arr1[len1-1].numerator, arr1[len1-3].denominator + arr1[len1-1].denominator);
            goto label;
        }
        if (arr1[0] != sample1)
            if (arr1[1] != sample1)
                while (true) {
                    fraction fr = fraction(arr1[0].numerator + arr1[1].numerator, arr1[0].denominator + arr1[1].denominator);
                    if (fr.numerator > N || fr.denominator > N) {
                        len1--;
                        for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
                            arr1[i] = arr1[i+1];
                        break;
                    }
                    if (fr < sample1)
                        arr1[0] = fr;
                    else if (fr > sample1) {
                        for (int i = len1; i > 1; i--)
                            arr1[i] = arr1[i - 1];
                        len1++;
                        arr1[1] = fr;
                    } else {
                        arr1[0] = fr;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    arr1[0] = arr1[1];
                    arr1[1] = arr1[2];
                    len1--;
                }
        int tmp = len1 - 2;
        if (arr1[tmp] != sample2) {
            while (true) {
                fraction fr = fraction(arr1[tmp].numerator + arr1[tmp+1].numerator, arr1[tmp].denominator + arr1[tmp+1].denominator);
                if (fr.numerator > N || fr.denominator > N) {
                    len1--;
                    break;
                }
                if (fr > sample2)
                    arr1[tmp + 1] = fr;
                else if (fr < sample2) {
                    arr1[len1] = arr1[len1 - 1];
                    len1++;
                    arr1[++tmp] = fr;
                } else {
                    arr1[++tmp] = fr;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else
            len1--;
    }

    if (len1 < 2) {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    /*
        indexForRemove убирает дроби, после генерации которых получится дробь с числителем или знаменателем больше, чем N.
        Например, при N = 5 в последовательности 1/2 2/3 1/1 он уберёт только первую дробь.
        Возможно, не самое лучшее решение по производительности.
    */
    for (int i = 0, prevLen = 0, indexForRemove = 0;; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0;; i1++) {
            arr2[i2] = arr1[i1];
            i2++;
            if (i1 + 1 == len1)
                break;
            long long numerator = arr1[i1].numerator + arr1[i1+1].numerator;
            if (numerator > N) {
                if (indexForRemove == i2 - 1)
                    indexForRemove++;
                continue;
            }
            long long denominator = arr1[i1].denominator + arr1[i1+1].denominator;
            if (denominator > N) {
                if (indexForRemove == i2 - 1)
                    indexForRemove++;
                continue;
            }
            fraction fr = fraction(numerator, denominator);
            arr2[i2] = fr;
            fractionSet.insert(fr);
            i2++;
        }
        if (indexForRemove != 0)
            memcpy(arr2, arr2 + indexForRemove, i2 -= indexForRemove);
        if (i2 < 2)
            break;
        fraction* tmp = arr1;
        arr1 = arr2;
        arr2 = tmp;
        len1 = i2;
        i2 = 0;
        prevLen = len1;
        indexForRemove = 0;
    }

    int limit = fractionSet.size() < n ? fractionSet.size() : n;

    cout << limit;
    set<fraction, decltype(&compare)>::iterator it = fractionSet.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++, it++)
        cout << '\n' << *it;
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

Вот вариант с перебором дробей. Практически все тесты опять WA, некоторые TL, правда, правильных ответов стало больше)
Может быть, я что-то упускаю?

```cpp
int main() {

    long long a, b, c, d, N; int n;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> N >> n;

    long long* r = new long long[400'000];
    int pos = 0, i = a + 1, j = b;
    double f = (double)a / b, s = (double)c / d;

    while (n && j <= N) {
        int lim = min(N + 1, (long long)ceil(s * j));
        while (i < lim) {
            if (gcd(i, j) == 1) {
                r[pos++] = i;
                r[pos++] = j;
                if (--n == 0)
                    break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        i = ceil(f * ++j);
    }

    cout << pos / 2 << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        cout << r[i] << ' ';
        cout << r[++i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: А может не химичить и сделать просто два цикла?

Comment: В чем, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Вопрос в том, как мне правильно решить задачу.

Comment: @Qwertiy цикл с перебором дробей и проверкой их сократимости? По времени не уложусь.

Comment: Почему? Надо всего 200 000 дробей вывести. Похоже, что для этого придётся проверить на простоту менее миллиона дробей: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Vd4.png

Comment: Вроде вот одни из самых плохих вариантов: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJB8v.png

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошо, я попробую.

Comment: @Qwertiy попробовал.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Как минимум у вас ошибка в выборе начального знаменателя, он может быть меньше `b`. Для `1 100 2 1 1000 10` первая дробь `1 1` а не `3 100`

Comment: @extrn благодарю, не подумал.

Comment: Откуда вообще вещественные числа взялись?

Comment: @Qwertiy это чтобы при увеличении знаменателя числитель делать сразу минимально возможным. Чтобы дробь i / j была больше a / b.

Comment: Это можно и в целых делать.

Comment: @Qwertiy как? Кстати, после замечания `extrn` не проходит где-то треть тестов, так что перебор - не вариант по времени. Может, можно как-то первое моё решение модернизировать?

Comment: А зачем ты их в массив сохраняешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошее замечание. Будем считать, что это авторское что-нибудь.

Comment: Так, а ты в курсе, что через break ты только из внутреннего цикла выходишь, а надо из обоих?

Comment: @Qwertiy вы про первый вариант или про второй? Если что, я обо всём в курсе.

Comment: А где эта олимпиадла в интернете? Чтоб проверить, перед тем как сюда писать?

Comment: @Mikhailo это задача от СПбГУ.

Comment: У тебя прога прошла хоть какую-то группу? Если да, то можешь поделиться решением, а то у меня падает на 10 тесте (WA). Я тоже делал через Деревва Штерна-Броко, но что-то не получаеся

Comment: @Олег ну, собственно, я уже написал, что у меня не проходит, а решение уже представлено в моём вопросе. Если у тебя не проходит только десятый тест, можешь, пожалуйста, скинуть своё решение?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен быстрый алгоритм перечисления всех несократимых дробей с заданным знаменателем. Каждая такая дробь кодируется деревом [Штерна-Броко](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/stern_brocot_farey)

Сам ряд несократимых дробей это ряд Фарея. Вот пример генерации рядя Фарея с сайта [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/farey-sequence/).

Собственно приведенный код легко модифицировать под вашу задачу.

Comment: Эм.. Как это отвечает на вопрос, если именно это дерево и приведено в вопросе?

Comment: @qwertiy это наводит на мысль, что нужен ряд Фарея, а код реализации дерева с ошибками.

Comment: Самое главное: автор не учитывает, что дробь может быть неправильная.

Comment: Так в первом решении именно это я и делаю.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия, но дерево упорядочено по возрастанию дробей, а нужна другая сортировка.

Comment: @Qwertiy если сделать сортировку внутри дерева, то новые дроби не будут правильно генерироваться. Или я чего-то не понимаю?